# Passing model to partial View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC, so far I have read that I have if I have lets say two form in one view, the recommended thing to do, is to have a View model which will have the model associate for each form, this forms are not related in any way just are in the home page, one form is for searching a fly and the other is contact form so as you can see there is no relationship of any kind.

this my "HomePageViewModel"

```
public class HomePageViewModel
    {
        public SearchFlyViewModel SearchFly;
        public ContactFormViewModel Contact;        
    }
```

, in my index file which is the homepage I have this at the top

```
@model Project.WebSite.Models.HomePageViewModel
```

now, I have a partial view inside my homepage, this partial view has the search fly form, I did it this way because I use the same form in a lot of places.

My partial view is _QuoteForm in which i have this at the top

```
@model Project.WebSite.Models.SearchFlyViewModel
```

when I tried to do this in my homepage

```
@Html.Partial("_QuoteForm", Model.SearchFly)
```

an error is showing up in runtime telling me this

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Project.WebSite.Models.HomePageViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Project.WebSite.Models.SearchFlyViewModel'.
```

Which I don't understand why because I did not pass the HomePageViewModel to my partial view, I passed Model.SearchFly which is of the type SearchFlyViewModel

if someone can help figure it out what I'm missing.

thanks

Comment: You're calling the correct method, the only thing I could guess is that maybe you made a mistake in your model, would be helpful if you included more source code

Comment: @Mate , thanks, that was the issue, I was not initializing the model inside my HomePageViewModel constructor therefore Model.SearchFly was null., Post your comment as answer to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter ( "**The model**" ) of the Html.Partial **should not be null.**

```
@Html.Partial("_QuoteForm", Model.SearchFly)
```

Verify

```
Model.SearchFly != null
```